# Wondering why Windows boot logo takes longer than when newer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I've had a new laptop for a couple of months now.
It's got a decent processor (Intel Core i7 3rd Gen 2.3Ghz), 1TB HDD (5400rpm, 8MB cache) and 2GB of GFX.

When it was new it'd boot in no time flat. I've been careful trying to only install the minimum programs I require.

Anyway, what I've noticed is that it now takes a long time to boot, I'm talking 3-5 minutes to get to the login screen. What in earth would change so that it now takes soo long just to do the core windows boot stuff?
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Run* the **msconfig** program, and view what programs are under the "Startup" tab.  If you have a "clean" system, then you would have something to compare with.

Comment: I have already disabled numerous services, set some to delayed and removed un-needed startup applications. It's not much left other than Avast Antivirus, wifi and touchpad. (I haven't messed with windows services of course)

Comment: Disconnect from the network and try temporarily uninstalling Avast (not disabling, as that might leave services running). Perhaps it's scanning something at startup?

Comment: The issues isn't login, it's when windows is booting with the black screen and logo.